# SQLServerManagementStudioのユーザ権限の設定

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Management Studio のとあるログインユーザーでストアドプロシージャの実行はできるが、変更や、プロシージャのソースコードの閲覧はできないように設定を行いたいのですがどのロールの設定、変更を行えばいいでしょうか。
ご教示お願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

特定のストアドプロシージャの実行権限をユーザーに与える場合。

```sql
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.procname TO username;
```

実行権限を持つロールを作る場合。

```sql
CREATE ROLE rolename;
GRANT EXECUTE TO rolename;
ALTER ROLE rolename ADD MEMBER username;
```